# Only the first element of the array has been output to the google sheet, I need all elements (except null/undefined elements) to be output

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

My script needs to get values from one sheet and put them into another sheet. It picks up the values correctly. However, when the values are being output to the other sheet only the first element is being output. I need all elements to be output. This could be achieved (I think) in one of two ways; either skip over/ignore the empty elements of the array when the values are being output or ignore the empty cells in the source sheet. Any help is appreciated. The script is below:

**Updated code:**

```
function exportArds() {

  var ards = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Newtownards");
  var export = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Export");
  var ardsLastRow = ards.getLastRow();
  var exportLastRow = export.getLastRow();
  var refValues = new Array(6);
  var amountValues = new Array(6);

 //get values for export
  refValues = ards.getRange("B12:G12").getValues();
  amountValues = ards.getRange("B13:G13").getValues();

 for(var i = 2; i<=6; i++){

   var a = refValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
   var b = amountValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);

   //get values, if any, in export sheet (used to check where the empty cells are for input) 
   var checkAmount = export.getRange(i, 4).getValue().toString();
   var checkDescription = export.getRange(i, 5).getValue().toString();
   export.getRange(i, 4).setValue(b[i-2]);
   export.getRange(i, 5).setValue(a[i-2]);
 }//close for loop
 Logger.log(a);
 Logger.log(b);
}//close function
```

When the values are being set to a cell correctly the next sheet however, if the array has say 2 values in it, the undefined will be output 4 times. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: `refValues = ards.getRange("B12:G12").getValues();` gets an array. Then `export.getRange(i, 5).setValue(refValues);` tries to assign it into a single cell. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @user6655984 the `i` in `(i, 5)` increments to change the row number that the value will be assigned to. That isn't the problem

Comment: JavaScript is weakly and dynamically typed - you don't need to do `var refValues = new Array(6); refValues = ....;` Simply `var refValues = ...;` will suffice. As far as your iteration issue, it is entirely avoidable if you use the object being iterated to control the iteration: `for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; ++i) {/** do stuff with myArr and i */}`. Please review JavaScript iteration in your preferred book / reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for this problem, I'm sure it could be a bit cleaner so feel free to comment any suggestions! The code is below:

```
function exportArds() {

  var ards = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Newtownards");
  var export = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Export");

  //get values for export
   var refValues = ards.getRange("B12:G12").getValues();
   var amountValues = ards.getRange("B13:G13").getValues();

  for(var i = 2; i<=6; i++){

    var a = refValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
    var b = amountValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);

  }//close for loop
  var aLength = a.length;
  var bLength = b.length;

  for(i = 2; i<=aLength; i++){
    export.getRange(i, 5).setValue(a[i-2]);
  }
  for(i = 2; i<=bLength; i++){
    export.getRange(i, 4).setValue(b[i-2]);
  }
}//close function
```